# Dynamically creating unique link or button for each result of a database query result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Basically, a list of results from a database query is inserted into a ul. I want the user to be able to click the result they are looking for and then have one of two things happen:

- A unique link is created (such as a php GET request) using the ID of
  the selected result
- A JS function is called via the onClick
  attribute, and the ID of the clicked result is sent as an argument.

The code below is what I have done so far - minus the functionality that I listed above.
The list as it is in the HTML:

```
    <ul data-role="listview" id="treesUL" data-inset="true" style="visibility: hidden">
            <li id="treesLI">
                <div class="resultNames">
                    <span class="donorName">Donor</span>
                    for
                    <span class="honoreeName">Honoree</span>
                </div>

                <div class="resultInfo">
                    <span class="treeName">common</span>
                    on: 
                    <span class="donationDate">Date</span>
                </div>

                <div class="resultDedication">
                    <span class="dedicationText">Dedication</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The javascript that edits the list, based on the results of the query which is stored in the myTrees array. This function is called via a XMLHttpRequest object.

```
function showTreeContent()
{
if (requestObj.readyState == 4) //Request completed
{
    //Retrieve the JSON encoded array, which is stored at index-key: media
    var text = requestObj.responseText;
    //alert(text);
    var myTrees = jQuery.parseJSON(text).media; 
    $('#treesUL').text('');

    //Alert the number of rows, for testing purposes
    alert(myTrees.length + " results.");

    //Loop through the JSON array, and add each element to a <li>, which is then added to the <ul>
    for(var i = 0; i < myTrees.length; i++)
    {
        var tree = myTrees[i];
        var li =$('#treesLI').clone();
        li.removeAttr('id');
        li.appendTo('#treesUL');

        //li.find('.treeLink').setAttribute("href", "somelink url");
        li.find('.donorName').text(tree['donor']);
        li.find('.honoreeName').text(tree['honoree']);
        li.find('.dedicationText').text("'" + tree['dedication'] + "'");

        if (tree['common'] != '')
            li.find('.treeName').text(tree['common']);
        else
            li.find('.treeName').text("Unknown Species");


        li.find('.donationDate').text(tree['date']);
        li.data('treeID','tree'+i);         
    }       
}
}
```

I tried surrounding the contents of the li tag with an a tag, and then editing the href of the a tag, but I was unable to get that to work. I'm using jQuery Mobile for this project also. Let me know if you need any more information - any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that I see strange is that you are calling `$('#treesUL').text('');` that deletes the contents of the ul and than in the loop you request `$('#treesLI')` which was deleted above.

What i would do is create the HTML as a string and append it to the ul.

Example.

```
var html = '';

for(var i = 0, length = myTrees.length; i < length; ++i)
{
    var tree = myTrees[i];
    html += '<li class="treesLI" onClick="somefunction('+ tree.id+')">';
    html += '<div class="resultNames"><span class="donorName">' + tree.donor + '</span>';
    html += 'for <span class="honoreeName">'+ tree.honoree + '</span></div>';
    html +='</li>';
    $('#treesUL').append(html);
}
```

As you can see i added an onClick handler that calls a function that receives a parameter.
You can use that onClick function to make a GET request with `$.axaj()`

If you don't want to use onClick you can do:

```
$('#treesUL li').click(function(event){

});
```

Some other observations:

- You can access the properties of an object using the `.` like this `tree.dedication`.
- You should do your for like this `for(var i = 0, length = myTrees.length; i < length; ++i)`
  it is 2 times faster in IE8

Comment: I implemented it this way, and it works but it lost the styling that I have implemented. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because in the example I set the `class` of the `li`, not the `id`. It is bad-practice to have multiple `id`'s. Change your style to use `class` instead of `id`